# Decrease cost per unit, with higher units

Tags: logarithms

I am working on a price model.
Basically what I want is the higher the units quantity, the lower the cost per unit should be. I need this in a formula somehow.

How would I do that

Something like this where the start value (price per unity) is 0.5
and it drops to a maximum of 0.10

[image]

Comment: There are countless ways of going about with this. For example, would
$$
\text{cost per unit} = \frac{\text{constant}}{\text{unit quantity}}
$$
(for some value of constant) do the trick? Also, why did you put a "logarithms" tag?

Answer (score 1):

Something like
$$
c = 0.1 + 0.4e^{-ku}
$$
where $u$ is the number of units and $c$ is the cost per unit. Adjust $k$ to adjust the speed of decay.

This is $0.1$ when $c=0$. Just shift it over if you want that when $c=1$.